# How can I get dubbing or subtitles to Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I'm from Czech Republic and I love playing Portal 2. I'm quite good an English speaker, but I just don't understand some parts of what they're saying. 
I was looking around the internet. But I can't find anything. Save me, please. 
**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Portal 2 does not have Czech dubbing.**

If you want to change all of he game's menus and interfaces into Czech, **change your Steam language to Czech**. This can be done in Steam interface by going to Steam/Settings/Interface/Select the language you wish Steam to use (requires Steam to restart)/Czech and restart Steam.

If you just want to change the closed captions, **go to the *developer console* and type cc_lang "czech"**. Note that closed captions must be enabled from within the game under Options/Audio/Closed Captions for closed captioning to be visible. By default, if your Steam language is set to Czech, you should not need to get to the developer console, but closed captions would still need to be turned on.

All this information can be found on [the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2156980).

And in case you were not aware [the wiki](http://portalgame.wikia.com/wiki/Developer_Console) describes how to access the developer console,

> The console can be enabled by going into Options->Keyboard->Advanced... and checking "Enable Developer Console (‘)". Now, by pressing the <kbd>‘</kbd> key, just under <kbd>Esc</kbd> on most keyboards, the developer console comes up.

Comment: Does Portal 2 have no language options in the game properties on Steam? Should be there to be honest. I don't have it so rightclick the game and select properties and check for a language tab please.

Comment: @scorcher24 Yes, there is. It however only lists English, German, French, Spanish and Russian. Unless there was an update; I own it, but it is not installed on this computer.

Comment: @Kareen can you use the console to choose languages that aren't present in Steam's language menu? It might be that those are the only ones you have available.

Comment: @kotekzot I don't have access to the game at the present time, but according to [Portal 2 Steam store page](http://http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/?snr=1_7_suggest__13), only English, French, German, Spanish and Russian have full audio support. Subtitles and/or closed captions are available in Czech, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, Hungarian, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Simplified Chinese, Swedish, Thai, Traditional Chinese and Turkish. I would think those are options within the game, as your answer suggests.

Comment: @Kareen if they are I wasn't able to find them. Probably an autoexec with the cc_lang command would be best.

Answer (score 5):

You can enabled subtitles under Options -> Audio -> Closed captioning.
"Full Captions" means every sound will be subtitled (e.g. "Door opens", "Turret activates", etc.) and "Subtitles only" means only speech will be subtitled.

Comment: I'd also add that this is true for pretty much every Source engine game - they all use the same basic configurator.

Comment: In my opinion this should be on by default, or explicitly asked when the game is run the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Or, go to the launcher in the `C:/Program Files/Valve/Portal 2/portal2/Launcher`.
When menu pops up select Czech instead of English.