# How can I get dubbing or subtitles in Portal?

Tags: portal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get dubbing or subtitles to Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64354/how-can-i-get-dubbing-or-subtitles-to-portal-2)

I would like to enable Czech dubbing/subtitles in Portal. Is that possible? How to do it?

Comment: You asked (with a different account) the same question for Portal 2 a month ago. The answer should be the same, so I vote to close this as duplicate.

Comment: As opposed to Portal 2, [Portal's Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/) doesn't mention Czech as a supported language.